# Facebook friend list in android' error

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve a list of my friends. I am using Facebook SDK 3.5.2. I have used many codes for getting the friend list, but it's not working.

I am using this code but it's not working:

```
Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new GraphUserListCallback() {

@Override
public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) 
{
    if(response.getError() == null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("users", "users " + users.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                       response.getError().getErrorMessage(), 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's not working'? What are you experiencing? Any errors?

Comment: @Neeku actually it return nothing. i mean that request is not working

Comment: Tried setting break points? Debugging?

Comment: @Neeku yes, i have done all the possible way, actually you know i can retrieve my facebook group videos,page videos, and other information/data, but here its not working for getting friend list.please help, if its possible for you.

Comment: I mean, have you tried setting break points at different parts of that code, e.g. if, else lines to see if it goes through the function, either if or else at all?

Comment: This is probably empty because none of your friends use the app.  As of 4/30/2014, you can only get friends which use the app.

Comment: @Neeku yes i have tried that, i think the request does't submit, and thus void oncompleted(..) method not called. i don't what is the problem. please Neeku do some thing

Comment: @Fosco It means that in this new Sdk(3.5.2) i am unable to fetch all my friends list? I am still developing it, so how should i accomplish this module. 
You know i have a huge tension, my BOSS says you should complete it, and he says that it is easy to get friends list, but i told him, that it is impossible to get it in this new Sdk.
Is there any other way to get the friend list.?

Comment: It isn't related to the SDK, it is an overall change that went into affect April 30th.  If you are looking to build an invite system, you can look into the invitable_friends or taggable_friends methods.

Comment: @Fosco So, frankly speaking what should i do now. its my project requirements to get the friends list. But as you say it is impossible. so should i leave this module(requirements) ???

Comment: Also, are you sure this is the newest SDK you're using? Based on this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/ the latest version is 3.15.

Comment: @Neeku yes Neeku, i am using the new Sdk, but according to "Fosco" comments it is impossible to get friends list , because Facebook has changed the policy after 4/30/2014

Comment: You figure out the issue, I am using this too and have two friends on but the list returns null

Comment: @Lion789 You should know about the Facebook policy, what they provide for developer. I think Facebook doesn't allow developer to get friends list in there application. Facebook has the very strict policy,

Comment: @Lion789 Please check out the FB policy, it has been changed on 4/30/2014, now its not providing the facility to a developer to get friend list in there application